# Material design date picker android change the layout

Tags: android, kotlin, material-components-android

Is it possible to change the position of the save button in the material design date picker in android? I am using full screen mode for the date picker and the save button is on the top right by default. I want to move the save button to bottom of the screen and change its color too. Is that possible? Also I want to add a clear button that clears the current selection instead of the save button at the top right of the screen. is this achievable?

Comment: You can change the color, but you can't add a new button to clear (there is a feature request for [it](https://github.com/material-components/material-components-android/issues/1332)) and you can 't move the save button on the bottom.